# BigQuery RAND() not accepting seed value

Tags: sql, random, google-bigquery, random-seed

I am trying to using the RAND() function and set a seed to generate a consistent set of 10 random values in my output following https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/RAND-Function_57344757#int_value

With this query I am getting the error: `No matching signature for function RAND for argument types: INT64.` :

```
rand_val as (
  select value
  from test
  where RAND(3) < 10/ (select count(value) from test))

select * from rand_val
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In BigQuery `rand()` does not take a seed argument.  Check the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#rand).

You can use a pseudo-random number generator.  For instance, if your table has a primary key, you can get 10 "random" samples with a key using `farm_fingerprint()`:

```
with t as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by farm_fingerprint(concat(pk, '3')) ) as seqnum
      from t
     )
select t.*
from t
where seqnum <= 10;
```

The second argument to `concat()` is a seed value.

Comment: Does anyone know the quality of these "random" selection? Is it good to create data for simulations, or estimation of population parameters based on samples? Does it pass Marsaglia's tests?